# Do I need spring batch if I have to process API services instead of CSV jobs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I'm writing an app where its primary objective is to *pull data from a service provider(XXX), convert and push it to another service provider(YYY) via HTTP REST.*

I can do this with a simple for-loop and I'm storing the last retrieved item creation date in a separate table. 
So I can continue pull items from last converted item whenever I needed and I'll be maintaining separate table to hold failed records and re-try those failed records with periodic intervals via CRON as well.

Do I still need to use SPRING Batch.
From what I can see is, it helps modular the code with a Reader, Processor and Writer.

Am I missing anything? Can I use spring batch and benefit for syncing data over HTTP services from point A - point B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Spring Batch for many reasons. Here is a non exhaustive list with an example related to your use case for each feature:

- Declarative I/O: Spring Batch provides a rich library of readers/writers and you don't have to write the I/O code yourself (open/close resources, read raw data, iterate on items, etc). Spring Batch is based on Spring Framework, you can leverage all Spring Framework features like AOP, transaction management, etc. **In your case, you can leverage the `RestTemplate` to GET/POST resources**
- Fault tolerance: The retry/skip mechanisms allow you to introduce some resilience in your batch jobs. **For example, in your case, retry processing an item if the rest service is temporarily down.**
- Chunk-oriented processing: This model is perfect for huge amounts of data. Data is read in chunks to avoid reading all the data set in memory. **In your case, you can have a call per page to get data from your rest end point**
- Transaction management: Spring Batch manages transactions for you so you don't lose data when errors happen. **In your case, you mentioned saving items to a database table, Spring Batch can manage the transaction commit/rollback for you**

Comment: Does the transaction management hold my item data(real processing data) as well or just the state of the item?